# Reliably complete Ajax request on page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a html/javascript application. When user refreshes the page or close the page i need to make a ajax request and then close the application.

I am using page unload event for this purpose.

I am calling 
window.onbeforeunload=beforeFunction;

beforeFunction will make the ajax request. But when i check in fiddler i dont see the ajax request. However if i debug the application and execute each line with f10 then i see the ajax request in fiddler.

thats how my ajax request is formed:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json){
              alert("success: " + json);
            },
            error: function(xhr, statusText, err) {
              alert("Error:" + xhr.status);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Please make js fiddle

Comment: a fiddle really wouldn't help with an unload issue?

Comment: thank you @olly_uk. Actually i dont know

Answer (score -1):

```
$(window).on('beforeunload' function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json){
          alert("success: " + json);
        },
        error: function(xhr, statusText, err) {
          alert("Error:" + xhr.status);
        }
    });
});
```

Try this....