# Prevent page unload until ajax fired

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, cross-browser

Sort of a duplication of this question: [Reliably complete Ajax request on page unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736921/reliably-complete-ajax-request-on-page-unload)

Basically I need to, prior to the page closing, fire a network request. I don't need the response value. However, simply putting it in my beforeunload handler doesn't work:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  // send ajax
}
```

It successfully fires in time with [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon), but I'm looking for a solution that is compatible with all browsers, and sendBeacon is not.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing nice. There are a bunch of rather hacky solutions out there (some of them mentioned in the MDN [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) article). The only thing you can do is use sendBeacon if it exists and otherwise fallback to some alternative.

Here is a quickly googled polyfill that does a synchronous ajax request if sendBeacon isn't supported: https://github.com/miguelmota/Navigator.sendBeacon